# JSDoc: How to document a type that is either Object or null?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

If I have a parameter of type Object or null, should I document it as {Object} or {?Object} or {Object|null}?

I read https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html and it says {?number} means either a number or null, but I'm not sure if I need this for objects, or just primitives.

Comment: The `{?…}` notation is for both objects and primitives. I was confused about it too and made some extensive research about it which you can read [here](https://gist.github.com/customcommander/5206dcb44670e34f6923b62c1781e1d2#opt-vs-nullable-vs-nonnullable)

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can use the `optional chaining` like `element?.addEventListener()` to check for null or not. So because of this, it's more intuitive for {?Object}. Just make sure that it is actually accepting `null` and not `undefined`. They have separate meanings.